# Docker '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p appd' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker

I am using openjdk:17-jdk-slim docker to create the docker image for my application. I am getting below error when creating a directory called 'appd'.

```
Step 5/8 : RUN mkdir -p appd
 ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
 ---> Running in b2aa09148abc
exec /bin/sh: exec format error
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p appd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Below is my docker file content. Can someone help me with this issue?

```
FROM reg.gitlab.com/xyz/collections/pks-artifacts/openjdk:17-jdk-slim

MAINTAINER  abc@xyz.com

COPY ./build/libs/col-app-*.jar app.jar

# Copy certificate file
COPY cacerts /usr/java/jdk-17.0.4.1/lib/security/

RUN mkdir -p appd
COPY appd appd
RUN chmod -R 777 /appd
```

Comment: It seems the base image is a Mac image (arm64/v8) but you're trying to build on an amd64 machine.

Comment: The "warning" is very pertinent, arguably much moreso than the (generic) error message used as a title.

Comment: Thanks Hans and Charles, I will update the that matches for amd64 and try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hans and Charles, after I changed the openjdk image to azul/zulu-openjdk:17.0.2 issue has been resolved.